# How to get the Object Value by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a following object (from a response) I want to retrieve the value  `2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30`.

```
{"success":true,"result":[{"0":"2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30"},35]}
```

Comment: use `response.result[0]["0"]`

Comment: besides the fact that this object comes from the response, the solution has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var obj = {"success":true,"result":[{"0":"2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30"},35]};
alert(obj["result"][0]["0"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var t ='{"success":true,"result":[{"0":"2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30"},35]}';
var tt = $.parseJSON(t);
alert(tt.result[0][0]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpeLbuLu/